# Equation of a Circle from parametric functions of sin and cos

Tags: trigonometry, circles, parametric

Given:

x = 2 cos (t/2)
y = 2 sin (t/2)

How do we find the equation of the circle? I know that x^2 + y^2 = 1,

where 
x = cos(t)
y = sin(t)

so 
x^2 = (2 cos (t/2))^2
y^2 = (2 sin (t/2))^2

How do you end up with x^2 + y^2 = 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle  x=2\cos\frac t2,y=2\sin\frac t2,$

$\displaystyle \cos\frac t2=\frac x2, \sin\frac t2=\frac y2$

Use $\displaystyle \cos^2\frac t2+\sin^2\frac t2=1$  to elimiante $t$

Answer (score 3):

We have always: $$\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$$ so here we have then $$x^2+y^2=4$$

Comment: Nice and simple explanation +1.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it is $\cos^2{p} + \sin^2{p}=1$ for any real value of $p$.  The value of $x^2+y^2$ is deduced from this, not the other way around.